# Multiple click on AJAX causing multiple php execution

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have this AJAX request

```
    function save_details()
    {
        $('#msgDialog').attr('class', 'alert alert-danger alert-dismissable hide');
        $('#msgResult').html('');

        BootstrapDialog.show(
        {
            title: 'Confirmation',
            message: 'Save the details?',
            buttons: [
            {
                label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel',
                cssClass:'btn btn-danger btn-sm',
                action: function(dialogItself) 
                {
                     dialogItself.close();
                }
            }, 
            {
                label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> OK',
                cssClass: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm',
                action: function(dialogItself)
                {
                    dialogItself.close();       //i have added this to close the confirmation box so that the user wont click it again

                    if(xhr_pm && xhr_pm.readyState !=4)
                    {
                        xhr_pm.abort();
                    }

                    xhr_pm = $.ajax(
                    {
                        type    :"POST",
                        url     : "  {{ Request::root().'/researcher/linkedin_interface/save_details' }} ",
                        data    :
                        {
                            id              : $('#modalClassifierData').attr('data-record'),
                        },
                        success:function(return_data)
                        {
                            //additional codes
                        }
                    });
                }
            }]
        });
    }
```

And I have backend code in Laravel handling the INSERT into the database. The problem is that, the user is doing multiple click(intentionally or unintentionally) and causing the same records to be inserted into the database hence now I have multiple records to deal with.

I am looking for ways to solve this with backend code rather than using JQuery just to cancel the Ajax request, because I noticed, even when the Ajax request is cancelled, it will still be executed in the server.

I have added validation to check the status prior to inserting the record, just that the interval between clicks is too short hence it does not detect that the record was added.

```
public function saveDetails()
{
    $request = \Request::all();

    $record = RecordsModel::with('record_details')->get()->first();

    //i even tried inserting sleep for 2 seconds but it still does not help, because the interval is just too short.

    $check = \LeadsModel::where('id', '=', $record->id)->where('source_id', '=',  1)->get()->count();

    if($check > 0)
    {
        //return already added in the database
    }

    $rollback_ctr = 0;
    DB::beginTransaction();

    //save lead
    $insert_lead = new LeadsModel();
    $insert_lead->name = $record->name;
    $insert_lead->country = $record->country;
    if(!$insert_lead->save())
    {
        $rollback_ctr++;
    }
    else
    {
        //save lead_details
        $insert_lead_detail = new LeadDetailsModel();
        $insert_lead_detail->contact_no = $request['no']
        if(!$insert_lead_detail->save())
        {
            $rollback_ctr++;
        }
    }

    if($rollback_ctr > 0)
    {
        DB::rollback();
        //return failed message
    }
    else
    {
        DB::commit();
        //return successful message
    }
}
```

Hope for a good advise to solve this problem. thanks

*UPDATE* Sometimes the function takes 5seconds to finish executing, so by that time, the user can close the dialog and then click the button and a dialog confirmation will appear again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed cancelling the AJAX request does not prevent backend code from being executed. The only way is to prevent the AJAX request from being sent.

The easiest way to do that is to set some Javascript variable before AJAX request is sent just to mark that the user has already clicked and request has been sent. Then on subsequent clicks from the user you can check that variable and if it is set do not send the AJAX request.

Another way would be to disable the button when it is clicked by the user.

Comment: I choose this, I do agree that jquery is more easier than the code behind validation. thanks though.

Comment: 100% agree but you will end up with double records if 2 users click on the same second on your ajax function

Answer (score 0):

disable the link/button whenever someone clicks on link/button so no further click eent can be triggered

```
$('selector').prop('disabled', true);
```